# Two different wireguard tunnels wg0 and wg1 via wlan0 and eth0 to the same wan ip

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, wireguard

I have following config:

two interfaces `eth0` connected via ISP1 and `wlan0` connected via ISP2 to the internet. Both connections have different IP addresses and allow internet connectivity.

I setup two wireguard interfaces `wg0` and `wg1`. `wg0` should always go via `eth0` (which is default anyway), and `wg1` should always go via `wlan0` interface.

The problem that I have is that I use same remote server-peer (eg. peer wan ip `11.11.11.11`) to connect to both `wg0` and `wg1` at the same time. So, when packet arrives on `wg1` it probably tries to send it back via `eth0` instead of `wlan0`. I tried to add static routing rules, but the thing is that I do not need to always route `11.11.11.11` via `wlan0`, since if connection comes from `eth0` it should also send it via `eth0`.

Is there some way to say - connection to `wg1` should always communicate via `wlan0`?

Other solution that I can see is possible here (and not sure if it would work), is to setup link aggregation for `eth0` and `wlan0`, but I read that it is not possible to aggregate different physical connections? It would be the best if I could have then single `wg0` interface available with whichever interface is up and running (`eth0` or `wlan0`).

This is current config:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:81:1e:50:c6:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.200/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0e:41:58:01:16:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.134/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.9.0.1/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: wg1: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.9.1.1/24 scope global wg0-client
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**UPDATE**

Adding the output of the command listed in the comments:

```
ip route

default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0 onlink
10.9.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.0.1
10.9.1.0/24 dev wg1 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.1.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.134
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.200

ip rule

0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

ip route show table local

local 10.9.0.1 dev wg0 proto kernel scope host src 10.9.0.1
broadcast 10.9.0.255 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.0.1
local 10.9.1.1 dev wg1 proto kernel scope host src 10.9.1.1
broadcast 10.9.1.255 dev wg1 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.1.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
local 192.168.0.134 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.0.134
broadcast 192.168.0.255 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.134
local 192.168.100.200 dev eth0 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.100.200
broadcast 192.168.100.255 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.200

ip route show table main

default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0 onlink
10.9.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.0.1
10.9.1.0/24 dev wg1 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.1.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.134
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.200
```

and wireguard configs:

```
wg0.conf

[Interface]
Address = 10.9.0.1/24
PrivateKey = xxx
ListenPort = 51820

PostUp = sysctl net.ipv4.conf.%i.forwarding=1 net.ipv4.conf.$(ip r l 0/0 | mawk '{print $5;exit}').forwarding=1
PostUp = sysctl net.ipv6.conf.$(ip r l 0/0 | mawk '{print $5;exit}').accept_ra=2
PostUp = sysctl net.ipv6.conf.%i.forwarding=1 net.ipv6.conf.$(ip r l 0/0 | mawk '{print $5;exit}').forwarding=1
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.0.0/24 -o $(ip r l 0/0 | mawk '{print $5;exit}') -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $(ip r l 0/0 | mawk '{print $5;exit}') -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.9.0.0/24 -o $(ip r l 0/0 | mawk '{print $5;exit}') -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = ip6tables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o $(ip r l 0/0 | mawk '{print $5;exit}') -j MASQUERADE

# Client 1
[Peer]
PublicKey = yyy
AllowedIPs = 10.9.0.2/32

wg1.conf

[Interface]
Address = 10.9.1.1/24
PrivateKey = zzz

PostUp = sysctl net.ipv4.conf.wg1.forwarding=1 net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.forwarding=1
PostUp = sysctl net.ipv6.conf.wlan0.accept_ra=2
PostUp = sysctl net.ipv6.conf.wg1.forwarding=1 net.ipv6.conf.wlan0.forwarding=1
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg1 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.1.0/24 -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg1 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
#PostUp = ip route add 11.11.11.11/32 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg1 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.9.1.0/24 -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg1 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
#PostDown = ip route del 11.11.11.11/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = qqq
AllowedIPs = 10.9.1.0/24
Endpoint = 11.11.11.11:7777

# Uncomment the following, if you're behind a NAT and want the connection to be kept alive.
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

wg command status:

```
interface: wg0
  public key: ddd
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: yyy
  endpoint: 11.11.11.11:51000
  allowed ips: 10.9.0.2/32
  latest handshake: 1 minute, 48 seconds ago
  transfer: 11.99 MiB received, 397.40 MiB sent

interface: wg1
  public key: ggg
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 35999

peer: qqq
  endpoint: 11.11.11.11:7777
  allowed ips: 10.9.1.0/24
  transfer: 0 B received, 525.95 KiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds
```

Comment: And you might as well provide how you configure WireGuard. If it's done using `wg0.conf` / `wg1.conf` files please also provide them (you should redact the keys). If it's done otherwise, please provide how it's done.

Comment: @A.B I just added to the question. btw. I do not have `nft` or `nftables` command.

Comment: 11.11.11.11 is openwrt router with 2 different interfaces. so both interfaces have completely different private/public keys.

Comment: I added output of wg command. you can see that wg0 is running, but wg1 is trying to send data, but I guess it uses eth0 instead of wlan0.

Comment: one is initiated from wg1, because that ISP has no public IPs. guess they use natting, so I have to initiate address from wg1 to 11.11.11.11. The other one (wg0) is initiated towards rpi.

Comment: btw. I managed to make this setup to work, just if I use different ip than 11.11.11.11 in this line `ip route add 11.11.11.11/32 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0`. I manage to get one connection via wg1, other via wg0, but in this case it is not single server, but two different wireguard server peers.

Comment: regarding default route for wlan0 - I guess system automatically sets default via wlan0 in case that eth0 is down as you say.

Comment: btw system is not old but latest dietpi bookworm debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current IPv4 setup as it's running, a policy routing rule relying on layer 4 (UDP port) can be used to have two different routes towards the same server.

So instead of using a route to the server through `wlan0` that would also override the one intended to happen through `eth0` [like](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/766282/two-different-wireguard-tunnels-wg0-and-wg1-via-wlan0-and-eth0-to-the-same-wan-i?noredirect=1#comment1461476_766282):

> ```
> ip route add 11.11.11.11/32 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0
> ```

one can instead rely on the WireGuard's source port to route differently, using a rule with a port selector and an alternate routing table selected by this rule. The easiest is choosing a fixed local WireGuard port. It doesn't matter if the remote system sees an other port because of ISP2's NAT: the routing rule matters only on the local system, not on the remote system.

Before the changes, there's no fixed source port and the route to reach 11.11.11.11 port 7777 is through `eth0` while the intent is to use `wlan0`:

```
# ip route get 11.11.11.11 ipproto udp dport 7777
11.11.11.11 via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.100.200 uid 0 
    cache
```

- use the fixed port to 51821 on `wg1`

  by adding this line to the `[Interface]` section of `wg1.conf`:

  ```
  ListenPort = 51821
  ```

  and meanwhile for immediate effect:

  ```
  wg set wg1 listen-port 51821
  ```
- prepare a new routing table (arbitrarily chosen as 1000) with a default route using the Wireless gateway to ISP2:

  ```
  ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 table 1000
  ```
- select this routing table when the locally initiated UDP source port is 51821 (`iif lo` is the special syntax for *locally initiated* instead of *routed/forwarded* so this won't disrupt other routed traffic if any that would use this same UDP source port by pure chance).

  ```
  ip rule add iif lo ipproto udp sport 51821 lookup 1000
  ```
- as Loose Reverse Path Forwarding is already selected (`rp_filter=2`) there's no further adjustment needed for replies because a default route exists somewhere (even if it's not on the same interface).

  So in both cases replies through `wlan0` are fine. Before and after:

  ```
  # ip route get iif wlan0 from 11.11.11.11 ipproto udp dport 51821 to 192.168.0.134
  local 192.168.0.134 from 11.11.11.11 dev lo 
      cache <local> iif wlan0
  ```

But now after these changes:

```
# ip route get 11.11.11.11 ipproto udp sport 51821
11.11.11.11 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 table 1000 src 192.168.0.134 uid 0 
    cache
```

The traffic, only for UDP source port 51821, meaning only for the `wg1` interface, uses `wlan0` instead of `eth0`. The other WireGuard interface won't be affected:

```
# ip route get 11.11.11.11 ipproto udp sport 51820
11.11.11.11 via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.100.200 uid 0 
    cache
```

The only two commands that have to be run (in addition to the listening port already added in `wg1.conf`) should probably be integrated as additional `PreUp`/`PostUp`/`PreDown`/`PostDown` entries in `wg1.conf`.

Comment: Thanks. I added these configs instead `PostUp = ip rule add iif lo ipproto udp dport 7777 lookup 7777` `PostDown = ip rule del iif lo ipproto udp dport 7777 lookup 7777`
`PostUp = ip route add 11.11.11.11/32 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 table 7777` `PostDown = ip route del 11.11.11.11/32 table 7777` which is probably not that good (since now it will route all udp 7777 via that table), but I guess I will never need udp 7777 destination other than this wireguard port.

Comment: It is basically what you sad just with destination port. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As you want. Is there a reason you didn't keep the source port? Because I see only advantages on keeping the local source port over the remote destination port as selector. If using PostUp even a local dynamic port can be used (eg: `$(wg show %i listen-port)` , look for `%i` in `man wg-quick`).